# Laravel - How to check reset password email sent successfully to the user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have following function `postEmail` in my `PasswordController.php` and calling when user trying to reset password.

```
/**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        //echo Input::get('ID'); die;
        $this->validate($request, ['ID' => 'required|email']);

        // Pass data to reset password mail template
        view()->composer('emails.password', function($view) {
            $view->with([
                'UserProduct1'   => 'UserProduct1',
                'UserProduct2'   => 'UserProduct2',
            ]);
        });

        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('ID'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['ID' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to check, reset email sent or not to the user in `laravel`.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: There would be a couple of ways to achieve this. You could do it by adding in some logic to the switch/case statements, or just add in a check to see if a row was inserted in to the password resets table - if the password reset was successful and email sent then there would be a record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.1 Mailer Class it's very easy to detect if mail was send

> **`Sending Mail`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send an e-mail reminder to the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendEmailReminder(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $mailSend = Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });//Here it returns 0 if email not send

        if ($mailSend === 0)
        {
            //Your Code
        }
    }
}
```

Here when you call **`Mail::send`** it will call this method https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L157 Then it will call **`sendSwiftMessage`** https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L388. Then it will call swiftmailer's **`send`** method https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php#L74 & as you can see when failing it returns $sent variable which is 0 if failed.

More https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail